# Are all points in a $T_1$ space limit points?

Tags: general-topology

According to the [definition of limit point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Definition).  A point $x_0$ of a $T_1$ space $X$ is a limit point if every open set containing it contains another point distinct from $x_0$.  Is every point a limit point?  I can show this if every singleton set is not open in a $T_1$ space.  But I don't know that either.  Please address both.

Comment: Do you mean "is every point a limit point of some subset"? What would happen if you considered the discrete space?

Comment: Oh, I see.  In that case every singleton is both open and closed and it's a $T_1$ space, so what you're saying is *not necessarily*.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  Consider Alex Youcis' comment - that the discrete space is $T_1$ and all singleton sets are both open and closed.